# Why aren't there any WS-* standards for REST web services?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, standards, soa

I was thinking into digging a little dipper into the REST type of web services and noticed that there aren't any specifications for it [as opposed to SOAP web services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_specifications).

Why is that?

Comment: http://www.jboss.org/reststar/specifications.html

Answer (score 6):

Each language uses its own standards. 
According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services):

> Unlike SOAP-based web services, there is no "official" standard for RESTful web services. This is because REST is an architecture, unlike SOAP, which is a protocol.

Comment: If only Wikipedia was accurate!  REST is a architectural style, not an architecture.  One of the core constraints of the style is that you must conform to a uniform interface.  Which means if you are doing REST over HTTP as 99% of people are doing then HTTP is your spec.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html - Http Uniform interface specification

http://tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/ - Latest revisions to HTTP spec

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-gregorio-uritemplate-04 - URI Templates

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-link-header-06 - Link Headers and link relations

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/  - Loads of links to specs for media types

These should be all the specs you need to get going to build a RESTful system over HTTP.

Are there specific WS-* specifications that you feel you are missing to be able to build as REST based system?

Comment: @Darrel: thanks. You've just identified the problem. This is all the REST standards there are. SOAP follows the same standards, but builds on them. REST insists we just stick with HTTP. That's not always enough, or we wouldn't have wasted all that time and money on the other standards.

Comment: @John Theoretically, REST doesn't limit you to HTTP, but practically it is currently the only mainstream option.  I think if you apply REST to the right problem domain then the specs that exist are sufficient.

Comment: @Darrel: the problem domains where something like WS-* are required are clearly the wrong problem domains for REST.

Comment: @John Although technically SOAP does comply to the HTTP, it only uses a small subset of its capabilities.  REST based systems can take full advantage of HTTP as an application protocol and gain many benefits that SOAP based systems lose.  In order for the SOAP based systems to regain those benefits you need to apply a bunch more tooling on top. It is certain that the WS-* specs allow systems to do many things that are not available in pure HTTP, but I would argue in most cases those functions are not needed for REST systems.

Comment: @John I agree completely.  Pick the right tool for the right job.

Comment: @Darrel: I agree that REST systems don't need those functions, and that a system that does need those functions should not use REST.

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least for Java there is JAX-RS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAX-RS, but i don't know if this is based on some other standards.

Comment: That's not a standard. "JAX-RS: Java API for RESTful Web Services is a Java programming language API "

Answer (score 0):

OData (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part1-protocol.html) is a standard for RESTful WebServices and should fit your needs (at least if you're using any MS framework).

Btw. if you want do use a standard and make the WebService as open and reusable as possible, WADL (http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/#x3-40001.3) the WSDL equivalent for REST could help.